# django template content not showing up

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

In my views i have pointed my code to login.html >But the alert in the ready function or the content so f the body are not seen on the UI.What am i doing wrong here

```
  {% extends "base/base.html" %}
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  alert('1');
  });
  </script>
     some code here
     some code here
     some code here
     some code here
     some code here
     some code here
  <b>{{response_dict.yes}} testing and testing and testinf</b>
  <b>{{a}}</b>
  <form action="/logon/" method="post" name="myform">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <b>Username</b><input type="text" name="username" id="username"></input>
  <br><b>Password</b><input type="password" name="password" id="password"></input>
  <b></b><input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
  <img src="/media/img/hi.png" alt="Hi!" /> <!-- This is working dude -->
  <img alt="Hi!" src="/opt/labs/lab_site/media/img/hi.png">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you extend a template, you need to specify in which block of your base template this markup will be rendered. Just add this into `base/base.html`:

```
{% block login %}{% endblock %}
```

in the place where the login form should be rendered, and then in `login.html` you'll have:

```
{% extends "base/base.html" %}
  {% block login %}
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    .....
    <img src="/media/img/hi.png" alt="Hi!" /> <!-- This is working dude -->
    <img alt="Hi!" src="/opt/labs/lab_site/media/img/hi.png">
    </form>
  {% endblock %}
```

Comment: i did not understand..So i am suppose to put your code in base.html right.what does enclose this html in the same block in login.html mean ??

Comment: what should i do in the login.html page??